# Android: Search box design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I want to design a search box in my app which would look as follows:
[image: search icon]

When I click on it, it should expand as follows:

[image: search box]

But, I am not getting how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You Should use `RelativeLayout` & set ImageView align_parent_top & align_parent_right
or if you use `LinearLayout` then you can try in this way:---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_my_profile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/txt_box_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_profile"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="My Profile"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_for_setting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My requirement is, initially the edittext should appear as the first image that I posted above and when I click on it, it should expand as I have illustrated in the second image.

Comment: for this just use RelativeLayout & make RelativeLayout orientation horizontal & take an edittext & imageview & in image view put in this way:-<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_for_setting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

Answer (score 0):

have you tried mobile Jquery utilities ?  it should not be difficult to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the search box is used in your app, it might suit best to use [Action Views in the ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView). This is Google's suggested way of including an expandable, responsive search box in an Activity.

For Android versions before SDK 11, you can achieve all the same functionality with a compatibility library, [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). While I haven't used expandable search bars in ActionBarSherlock myself, it looks like it is possible here using a SearchView.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, for quick response. But, min Sdk version of my app is 8, while this has been introduced since api level 11. Is it available in compatibility package?

Comment: Just edited my answer with details on the compatibility library that should give you the functionality you need on SDK version 8.

Answer (score 0):

Create An Linear layout. set its background as your full edit box image. inside that linear layout add one editbox and button. set the background of button as android:background="@drawable/searchbtn".
set the background of edit box as a none image(transparent image).its done.